# Concavity of distance to the boundary in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $(M, \partial M)$ be a Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature $\geq 0$ and convex boundary $\partial M$ of sectional curvature $\geq 0$. Then it is well known that the function $\operatorname{dist}(\partial M , x) : M \setminus \partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is concave.

Assume $M=\mathbb{H}^2$ i.e. the hyperbolic plane. In the upper half plane model the right quadrant is a convex set $C$. What can be said about the eigenvalues of the hessian of $\operatorname{dist}(\partial C , x) : M \setminus \partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $p \in C$. Clearly one eigenvalue will be $0$ what is the second?

Is there a quick reference?

Edit: Short answer is $\tanh(d(p,\partial C))$ (see answer below).

Comment: I think, your 1st paragraph is missing some assumptions about the boundary, I think you want the boundary to be convex.

Comment: Since $M$ is trivially a convex subset in $M$. The boundary comes from a convex set.

Comment: That would be a wrong notion of convexity. The correct one is in terms of the 2nd fundamental form of the boundary being negative-definite (with respect to the normal vector field pointing inside of the manifold).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "wrong notion of convexity", because I never said something about the boundary being convex. You claim that the statement "$M$ Riemannian manifold with $sec \geq 0$ and $\partial M \neq \emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ $\operatorname{dist}_{\partial M } : M \setminus \partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is concave" is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample? - I am actually very certain that the statement is correct. Your manifold should be complete this assumption might be missing but additional assumptions on the boundary are not necessary.

Comment: Just take your manifold to be the Euclidean plane with an open round disk removed. The distance to the boundary will be convex, not concave. Of course, if you want to have a geodesically complete manifold then there are no examples since any manifold with boundary is geodesically incomplete.

Comment: The euclidean plane with the open disc removed is complete that is fine but it does not satisfy the curvature assumption.
To see that take two points on the boundary of the disc. The geodesic connecting them will be an arc on the circle. Now pick a third point not on the disc. Then the triangle looks hyperbolic. In particular the toponogov theorem does not hold for curvature $ \geq 0$. 
The distance function being convex comes from the fact that you have a hadamard space i.e synthethic curvature $\leq0$, which gives you the wrong bound for the curvature.

Comment: Your are confusing two notions of curvature. In your question you are talking about Riemannian sectional curvature, while in the comments you are using Alexandrov's definition. They are not equivalent (for manifolds with boundary.)  My example (as a Riemannian manifold) has zero sectional curvature, but indeed does not have curvature $\ge 0$ in Alexandrov's sense. In order to have curvature $\ge 0$ in Alexandrov's sense, the boundary should be convex.

Comment: Ah, thanks now I see the issue. I missed the point that Alexandrov's definition does not extend to spaces with boundary.

Comment: Not a problem. Alexandrov's **definition** works to any metric space, it is just the equivalence (of the lower/upper curvature bounds) with the Riemannian definition fails if the boundary is nonempty. I think, this equivalence was first proven by Alexandrov himself in 1957 in the case of upper curvature bounds (a long paper written in German, so I could be mistaken). For the lower curvature bounds, the result is due to Toponogov. The standard way to fix this discrepancy between the two definitions is to impose the convexity condition for the boundary (on the Riemannian side).

Comment: ... This convexity condition is quite standard in differential geometry and helps with other things as well. For instance, it is used in the minimal surface theory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the Hessian always has a null direction along the geodesic joining $p$ to the closest point of $\partial C$. Since the Hessian is symmetric, the remaining eigenspace will be orthogonal to this geodesic, meaning it will coincide with the tangent space to the level set of the distance function $r = \operatorname{dist}(\partial C,\cdot).$ The restriction of the Hessian to this tangent space is just the second fundamental form of the level curve $\{ r = r(x) \}$, so the corresponding eigenvalue is just the geodesic curvature of this curve.

It's well known that in the half-plane model (with your $C$) these curves (known as hypercycles) are just the Euclidean rays from the origin. You can deduce this fairly simply: the geodesic joining $\{r=r(x)\}$ to $\partial C$ must be perpendicular to both $\partial C$ and $\{r = r(x)\}.$ The former implies it's an arc of a circle centred at the origin, and thus the latter means the tangent to $\{r = r(x)\}$ is radial.

Thus the eigenvalue you're looking for is just the geodesic curvature at $x$ of the ray from the origin to $x$. A routine calculation (just parametrise this curve by arclength and compute its covariant acceleration) should result in the answer $\tanh(r(x)).$